# Trying to run VmWare on Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, vmware-player, manjaro

I'm trying to run VMWare on Manjaro but this message keeps appearing:

[image]

I am pretty new to linux, [this was one of the tutorials that I was
following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_3BUudWe-o). The steps that I was following were in the description.

I wasn't able to run the command `yay -S vmware-systemd-services`, because this error popped up:

> -> Could not find all required packages:
> vmware-systemd-services (Target)"

If someone can help me that would be great because I can't seem to find a solution to these errors.

Comment: I do not use Arch, but I do use VMware. Kernel Headers are need for the VMware Tools.  Try this article:  https://low-orbit.net/arch-linux-how-to-install-kernel-headers

Comment: Thank you for your time,it works now.

Comment: Good to know. I posted an answer for you and I trust you will acknowledge the answer.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to run VMWare on Manjaro but this message keeps appearing:
> [kernel headers missing]

I do not use Arch, but I do use VMware. Kernel Headers are need for the VMware Tools.

Try this article on how to install headers:

[Install Kernel Headers](https://low-orbit.net/arch-linux-how-to-install-kernel-headers)

To install kernel headers on Arch just run the following:

> pacman -S linux-headers
>
> You may also need to reboot depending on why you were installing the
> kernel headers.
>
> You can actually install a specific version of the kernel headers like
> this:
>
> pacman -S linux-armv7-headers-3.16.1-1